# Multiple Plots with ggplot2: Non-closing files and blank pages

Tags: r, pdf, plot, ggplot2

I have a strange phenomenon when storing multiple ggplot2 plots as pdf. When storing with ggsave, I am getting B_ggplot.pdf OK, but A_ggplot.pdf does not close the file (it seems locked). The old method sometimes generates a blank page. There seem to be race conditions, but I cannot put my finger on it.

Can somebody help me understand this?

Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)

# plot A
figureA <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=hp)) + geom_point()
# plot B
figureB <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=carb)) + geom_point()

# store PDFs using ggplot2
ggsave(file="D:/A_ggplot.pdf") # OK
ggsave(file="D:/B_ggplot.pdf") # PDF with empty page

# store PDFs the old way
pdf(file="D:/A.pdf") # OK
print(figureA)
dev.off()
pdf(file="D:/B.pdf") # hangs and when closing RStudio, writes file
print(figureB)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Have you tried closing all graphics devices by running `dev.off()` until you get an error?

Comment: Thats seems to do it, wrt to the closing file issue. However, I still have a blank pdf page for A_ggplot.pdf... ?

Comment: I tried your code and got around your issue with `ggsave(file="D:/A_ggplot.pdf", plot=figureA)` and `ggsave(file="D:/B_ggplot.pdf", plot=figureB)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me.  You need to call `ggsave` after each plot. From the documentation you'll see that `ggplot` uses the `last_plot()`. I'm not on Windows, so I've changed the paths. Anyway:

```
library(ggplot2)

# plot A
figureA <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=hp)) + geom_point()
ggsave(file="~/A_ggplot.pdf") 

# plot B
figureB <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=carb)) + geom_point()
ggsave(file="~/B_ggplot.pdf")
```

Otherwise you need to specify it, e.g. with:

```
ggsave(file="~/B_ggplot.pdf", plot = figureB)
```

The old way works without problems for me:

```
pdf(file="~/A.pdf") # OK
print(figureA)
dev.off()

pdf(file="~/B.pdf") # OK
print(figureB)
dev.off()
```

Please provide a `sessionInfo()`. Be sure to update your packages. Be sure to run the code in a fresh R session.

Comment: Yes, that did it. A little detail that I did not consider. Thanks!